# What does it mean for a point charge to be "driven" by a planar monochromatic E&M wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, charge, terminology, classical-electrodynamics

I have a point charge at the origin that is being "driven" by a planar monochromatic E&M wave $\vec{E}=E_0 \cos (kz-wt)\hat y$ and I need to find the radiation fields $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$. What is happening in this situation?? What I imagine is that the plane wave is hitting the charge and giving it kinetic energy, which causes it to accelerate up to some velocity. Then, the fact that the charge is accelerated creates a radiation field. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

The word "driven" is used as in the context of forced oscillations when an external driveR forces the driveN system to oscillate.

In this case the incident oscillating electric field is forcing the charge to oscillate.
The charge absorbs energy, accelerates and so emits electromagnetic radiation of the same frequency.
If it is a free charge then it is called [Thomson scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_scattering).

You may find this [link](http://web.hep.uiuc.edu/home/serrede/P436/Lecture_Notes/P436_Lect_14p5.pdf) helpful?

Comment: Does the point charge have collinear $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{a}$ after being hit by the wave? That is, does the charge obtain a velocity *and* an acceleration in the same direction after receiving energy from the wave?

Comment: @loltospoon The answer to your question is in the reference that I gave you "The particle will move in the direction of the oscillating electric field, resulting in electromagnetic dipole radiation."

Comment: Yes, but that was too vague. "In the direction of the oscillating electric field" - meaning it will accelerate in the same direction as the oscillations? Or will it accelerate in the direction of propagation of the electric field?

Comment: In the direction of the electric field.

Comment: That's the vague part I'm trying to resolve. From my perspective, the electric field has 2 types of motion - oscillating and propagating. Which motion does the particle "copy"?